# How do I remove kext files after uninstalling Norton Antivirus on mac to then install Avast?

Tags: macos, terminal, avast, norton-antivirus, kext

I removed Norton after having problems with it interfacing with MacOS on many levels. I proceeded with the standard Norton uninstall and found that it seemed to work. However, when adding Avast I found that Avast will not install due to existing Norton/Symantec files existing.

I have tried file cleaners and the standard norton uninstall cleaners.

It seems that 4 items still remain and I am unable to remove them.

when running 
`kextstat | grep -v com.apple`

i find:

com.symantec.SymXIPS (9.0.1)

com.symantec.internetSecurity.kext

com.symantec.nfm.kext (9.0.0)

com.symantec.ips.kext (9.0.1)

When trying to unload am met with this (below) or a kernel panic.

```
Password:*****************
(kernel) Can't remove kext com.symantec.internetSecurity.kext; services failed to terminate - 0xdc008018.
Failed to unload com.symantec.internetSecurity.kext - (libkern/kext) kext is in use or retained (cannot unload).
```

Through some research I have found that some resources have stated that I should enter safe mode and run `csrutil disable`

(due to having File Vault enabled)

Yet again after restart I get the same error of unable to terminate and Avast still fails to install.

Comment: Download https://support.norton.com/sp/en/us/home/current/solutions/kb20080427024142EN and run the removal tool. Otherwise look up Norton/Symantec removal/sleanup tool for Mac OS.

Comment: I have downloaded it and run it multiple times. it still leaves the .kext intact

Comment: Try running this as root or su.... `kextunload /System/Library/Extensions/com.symantec.internetSecurity.kext`. You might also be sure you are running the removal tool as root or elevated SU as well. Quick thoughts and ideas.... I'd also reboot after doing those things and then check afterwards if that helped or not. Let me know what you get when you try and get to it.