# Fully uninstall Norton from mac

Tags: macos, uninstall, norton-internet-security

Ok, I made a huge mistake: I put Norton onto my mac and now I cannot get rid of it!

System: macOS Catalina 10.15.7

I tried:

1. Drag app icons to trash and select "uninstall"
2. Run Norton's utility here (https://support.norton.com/sp/en/us/home/current/solutions/kb20080427024142EN)
3. Using Terminal, I did the following:

a) I had to give it Full Disk Access first

b) $ sudo find / -name "norton" >> norton.txt

I was able to get rid of everything in the norton.txt file, but when I rerun find I get "Operation not permitted" for a lot of files & directories in "/private/var/folders" and "/System/Volumes/Data/"

I know Norton isn't fully removed because each time I try to install Avast it tells me:

"Norton Internet Security has been detected. To install the Avast product, please uninstall the incompatible software first."

(I posted this in StackOverflow but they suggested I try over here)
(I see a similar question here: [How do I remove kext files after uninstalling Norton Antivirus on mac to then install Avast?](https://superuser.com/questions/1535202/how-do-i-remove-kext-files-after-uninstalling-norton-antivirus-on-mac-to-then-in) but I am not sure if I am able to unload the kext files because my Find command may not even find them yet!)

Comment: You should determine, if you can or cannot unload the kext files, and edit your question with the necessary information to answer your question.

Comment: I agree.  But I do not understand why I still get "Operation not permitted" when I run "sudo find" and Terminal has full disk access.  This is preventing me from even finding the kext files!

Comment: Solved!  It turns out I needed to disable System Integrity Protection first and then find and remove the offending files (thank you to @JMY1000) -- posted here (https://superuser.com/questions/1595874/operation-not-permitted-using-find-in-macos-terminal?noredirect=1#comment2441373_1595874)

Comment: Submit an answer instead of a comment

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I needed to disable System Integrity Protection first and then find and remove the offending files.

> 1. Go to System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy panel, and give Full Disk Access to Terminal.
> 2. Turn off System Integrity Protection (not generally recommended.) This disables full protection for system-related items on the disk, as
>    well as some other protections including restricted access via
>    Terminal.

Source: [Operation not permitted using Find in macOS Terminal](https://superuser.com/questions/1595874/operation-not-permitted-using-find-in-macos-terminal?noredirect=1#comment2441373_1595874)