# Operation not permitted using Find in macOS Terminal

Tags: macos, permissions, terminal.app

This is a lead-up to my main question here ([Fully uninstall Norton from mac](https://superuser.com/questions/1594485/fully-uninstall-norton-from-mac))

I get "Operation not permitted" when running "sudo find" in terminal on macOS.

I have given terminal Full Disk Access in System Preferences, Security & Privacy.

Here is the command I run:

% sudo find / -name "norton" >> norton.txt

It returns some files and directories into the .txt file, but I get two screens full of Operation not permitted errors, mostly in /System/Volumes/Data/private/var/folders/

Why is this happening?  How do I fix it?

Comment: Is System Integrity Protection enabled?

Comment: @JMY1000 - thank you!  That was the problem.  I was able to remove Norton and install a different av provider.

Answer (score 4):

[macOS restricts Terminal access to certain parts of the disk by default.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/339862/ls-operation-not-permitted-mojave-security) You can disable this one of two ways:

1. Go to System Preferences > Security & Privacy and give Full Disk Access to Terminal.
2. Turn of System Integrity Protection (not generally recommended.) This disables full protection for system-related items on the disk, as well as some other protections including restricted access via Terminal.

Comment: How did you do the second point? I see no such option in the system preferences ...

Comment: On the other hand, my mac does have it, but after giving full access and restarting the terminal, I still get the same "Operation not permitted".